# How to concatenate tagged document

Tags: itext, accessibility

is there any possibility to concatenate 2 existing tagged document and merge the tagged structure behind them?

Thanks in advance, Salvo.

Comment: There might be a possibility if you briefly explain what exat are you trying to achieve...And post some of your code snippets that you have tried..

Comment: Here is what i wrote in the mailing list, is a little bit more detailed:

[Hi, 
I'm working on tagged documents for accessibility reason, I've produced a couple of them and I need as well to produce a big document resulting from the concatenation of the single ones.

I would ask you if is there any possibility to concatenate 2 existing tagged document and merge the tagged structure behind them?

Or I have to create a new one document?]

Comment: I don't have a code snippet, I've just tried the examples tagged with the #Concatenate PDFs in the itext example page and I realize that in the merged document I loose the tagged structure behind every single doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example in the Unit-tests of iText: [`TaggedPdfCopyTest`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5885/tree/trunk/itext/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/TaggedPdfCopyTest.java). As already explained on the mailing-list, you need to use the setTagged() method on PdfCopy and you need to use the [`getImportedPage()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html#getImportedPage%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader,%20int,%20boolean%29) method with the `keepTaggedPdfStructure` parameter set to `true`.

Comment: I apologise for my abuse, I didn't notice it was so fast to get an ansewer so I tried in both channel. Thanks again.